# recurrences for Gegenbauer polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, recurrence-relations

Is there a recurrence relation or identities which can express a Gegenbauer polynomial for an integer n through an another Gegenbauer but only for an integer n+1 ?

thanks

Comment: Do we assume that you are familiar with the recursion formula for $C_n^{(\lambda)}$ in terms of $C_{n-1}^{(\lambda)}$ and $C_{n-2}^{(\lambda)}$?

Comment: @CyeWaldman yess